# Jquery Update DIV contact not Adding a new

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

[image]

Hello all i am writing a code to make and ajax call to add new record in Database 
and every time a make a call a want to echo its done successfully

what is happing here is showing a new line every time i click on a button but 
what i need is make it just one line and its content change every time i update the database

My Jquery Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(".new_button").click(function() {

var element = $(this);
   var  r_n = $("#x").val();


    var test = $("#content").val();

    var dataString = 'content='+ test;








        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
  url: "new_recepit.php",
   data: dataString+'&x='+r_n,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){



 $("#display").after(html);   

 document.getElementById('content').value='';
 $("#flash").hide();

  }


});



    return false;
    });



});
</script>
```

My PHP file code

```
    'if($insert){
    $recepit_id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $_SESSION['last_Recepit_id']=$recepit_id;
    $msg="New Recepit scuccessfuly created with Id :";
    }
    else{
    $msg="No New Recepit has created there is some Error";
?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">

<tr class="comment">
<td style="padding:14px;" class="comment_box" align="left"><b><?php echo $msg.$recepit_id; ?></b></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of after() function use html() function. 
Replace the below code

```
$("#display").after(html);
```

With

```
$( "#display" ).html(html);
```

Assuming #display is used to display the message only.

Comment: i am trying but i am new still have only 1 reputation